# How to get the count of unit tests present in the project

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-gradle-plugin

I have written some unit tests for my android project. I want to know if there exists a way I can get the count of the total number of unit test executed when I run `gradlew test`

In the case of UI tests, the count is known to us at the time of test running.

```
V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=26
```

I wonder if there exists some way to get so in Unit tests. I am running the tests on CircleCi and want to know the test count.

Answer (score 0):

You can get count of separate test [Unit and Instrumental test] with details. For this you have to do two things.

1. Run : `gradlew test connectedAndroidTest`
2. After complete test visit your **Build** folder.

And you will get [image]

And if you visit each **index.html** you will get all test count with details.

Comment: Thanks, @Tariqul for your detailed explanation but I am running the tests on CircleCi and I want to show the test count to everyone who sees those reports. Is there any way to get the test count there.